# Send data from a Service's thread to an Activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I saw how to send data from a thread declared into an Activity to this Activity itself. However, I don't know how to get data from a Service's thread and then send it to my Activity. I'm a bit confused, do I still need to use Handler?

**EDIT:** I have found the solution! Let's sum up. First, declare your Handler inside your Activity and before starting your Service, put some extra data by adding a new Messenger, linked to your Handler.

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    ConnectionDetector m_cd;
    Intent m_networkListenerService;

    public Handler m_handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)  // This is where main activity thread receives messages
        {
            Bundle  bundle;
            if (msg.what == 1)  //  1 MEANS NEW ELEMENT
            {
                bundle = msg.getData();
                System.out.println( bundle.getString("name"));
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        this.m_networkListenerService = new Intent(this, Network.class);
        this.m_networkListenerService.putExtra("Messenger", new Messenger(this.m_handler));
        this.startService(this.m_networkListenerService);

    }
}
```

Then, inside your Service class (you can do the same with an IntentService class), get your Messenger back and send it as a parameter to your Thread class:

```
public class Network extends Service
{
    NetworkListenerThread  m_networkListenerThread;
    Messenger   m_messenger;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()  {   super.onCreate();   }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {   super.onDestroy();  }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if (intent != null)
        {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null)
            {
                this.m_messenger = (Messenger)extras.get("Messenger");
                this.m_networkListenerThread = new NetworkListenerThread(m_messenger);
                this.m_networkListenerThread.start();
            }
        }
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Once again, get your Messenger back into your Thread class:

```
public class NetworkListenerThread extends Thread
{
    private static final int BROADCAST_PORT = 4415;
    private DatagramSocket  m_socket = null;
    private Messenger   m_messenger; 

    public  NetworkListenerThread(Messenger messenger)
    {
        this.m_messenger = messenger;
    }
}
```

Finally, wherever you want to send your data, use this code:

```
Message msg = Message.obtain();   //  Creates a message from the message handler to send it back to the main UI
msg.what = 1;   //  Specifies the type of message
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1); //  Object of size 1 in which we put the data in
bundle.putString("name", name); //  Key + data (which is a String)
msg.setData(bundle); //  Attaches the bundle to the message
try {   this.m_messenger.send(msg); }  //  We use the Messenger from the main thread to send the data 
catch (RemoteException e) { e.printStackTrace();    }
```

Comment: ya you have to use handlers, you need to have a messenger in activity that sends its id to another messenger in Service that takes the id. then after parsing the data sending it back to the messenger ID. it is a complicated function. or you can use broadcast receiver to communicate between which is easier however I prefer the first one

Comment: Do you have any clues on how to do this?

Comment: Ok I have found the solution. See my edited post.